# WPF - How do I make a stop button using boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to bind a button to be able to change a Boolean value from true to false.

I do not want to affect the buttons visibility, or IsSelected. Ultimately i am making a Stop button that just depends on if a property is true or false.

```
    private bool _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return _isRunning;
        }
        set
        {
            _isRunning = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsRunning");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand Stest { get; set; }

    public StartTest()
    {
        Stest = new RelayCommand(Test, Test11);
    }

    public async void Test(object host)
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        int number = 1;
        while( IsRunning == false)
        {
            OutPut = number.ToString();
            number++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }

    }

    public bool Test11(object host)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I'd like to be able to change the value of "IsRunning" to True to stop the while loop.

Comment: What is your XAML?

Comment: You can have a command or a click event handler, or you can use a ToggleButton (or CheckBox) and bind its IsChecked property to a boolean property of the viewmodel. Your StartTest class should implement INotifyPropertyCanged and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter for the boolean property.

Comment: Are you looking for toggle functionality? As in, when you click the button you want `isRunning` to turn `true/false` based on current value?

Comment: Ok so i added the Inotify, and the OnPropertyChanged, so if the command is simply changing the booleaan from false to true, would it be something like:
public void Changebool()
{
_isRunning = true;
}

?

Comment: @BobG please see my answer below.

Comment: There is a wealth of information in existing questions explaining how a button can interact with a view model, including setting `bool` values. See e.g. marked duplicate.

Comment: To be fair there is a ton of information on enabling and disabling the button, or affecting the button's properties. Your proposed "duplicate answer" does not answer this question as it has to do with the visibility of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind the `Command` of the button to a command in your code, which can call a function. The said function would simply toggle the value of `IsRunning`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private bool _isRunning = false;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _isRunning; }
        set { _isRunning = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsRunning"); }
    }

    public RelayCommand IsRunningCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsRunningCommand = new RelayCommand(ToggleRunning);
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void ToggleRunning()
    {
        IsRunning = !IsRunning;
    }
}
```

Your button `XAML` would be like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Name="BtnToggle" Width="100" Height="28"
        Content="Toggle"
        Command="{Binding IsRunningCommand}"/>
```

If you're not looking for a toggle functionality, but simply to set `IsRunning` to `false` whenever the button is clicked, simply change the function to this:

```
public void ToggleRunning()
{
    IsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much - I wasn't sure if i needed the icommand to pass it and if i did i didn't know how to write it properly - thank you so much